# htaccess rewrite not working as expected just change my address in addressbar, no rewriting at all

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have folder/file structure as:

```
rootFolder/
  lowRes/lowres.php
  hiRes/hires.php
  sys.php
```

Basically, I want to do rewrite such as that when user calls for page site.com/img_0001_hq.html, .htaccess to rewrite it to sys.php?1=img_0001_hq. Also, I want to limit acceptable emdings to ".html" and "/" and if ending like so is not present I want to call sys.php?1=p_404. Rewriting is doing as expected BUT when it comes to errors...

When I call page site.com/hiRes/hires.php or site.com/lowRes/lowres.php, rewriting is not working, scripts (hires.php and lowres.php) run, and report errors, normally in lack of variables from sys.php which is not triggered. Also, when I call pages site.com/hiRes or site.com/lowRes, sys.php runs, BUT, wrong. Also, when calling these addresses, address in browser changes to site.com/hiRes/?1=p_404 or site.com/lowRes/?1=p_404. What the heck is going on?! :D

Oh, yeah, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|.html)$ sys.php?1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sys.php?1=p_404 [L]
```

I am going nuts over this... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some conditions that exclude sys.php (and whatever else you don't want re-written). What's probably happening is that after the first rewrite, the URI becomes `sys.php` and is put back through the rewrite engine (mod_rewrite will do this until either the URI stops changing or it reaches the maximum number of internal redirects, causing 500 Server error):

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sys\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|.html)$ sys.php?1=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sys\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sys.php?1=p_404 [L]
```

Comment: Huh, this works, but, not in a way I want it to... :) So, I just had to create a .htaccess in each folder (lowRes, hiRes) to forbid enterance, and I removed line "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sys.php?1=p_404 [L]" from www folder, and problem is now solved. :)